# TYPO3 4.7.19 piBase $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] get blank

Tags: typo3, pibase

I have a TYPO3 piBase BE extension. I have debuged the code and I got the following issue:
When I have logged into BE with "www", I got value of `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']`. But when I have logged into BE without "www", I got a blank array in `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user`.

I have tried:

```
$GLOBALS['BE_USER'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_tsfeBeUserAuth');
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->start();
```

But still I got a blank array when login without "www".

Comment: Check with Install Tool, what do you have in [SYS][cookieDomain] and [BE][cookieDomain]?

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi thanks for comment. just now, I have set cookiDomain (mydomain.at) for both SYS and BE. but still I got blank array $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user. It's only happens when I am login with without "www". any suggestion? might be your one comment save my life :)

Comment: What do you mean "I have logged into BE with "www"" etc? So you use 2 different domains?

Comment: @SybillePeters No I don't have different domains. eg. I'm getting blank this array $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] If I logedin with this url www.mydomain.at/typo3